# porting windows service to windows azure

Tags: .net, azure

I have a windows service application which executes jobs, is it possible to port the app to Windows azure?

Like the app will run continuously and collects data from third party devices.

Comment: What kind of third party devices? You mean services?

Comment: Devices with Ethernet, which listens to proprietary protocols. Like your home security panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Azure offers the notion of **worker role** which is precisely suited for scheduled and/or intensive background tasks. Porting a classical Windows Service (that does not touch/interact with the OS) toward Azure is straightforward if the service is implemented in .NET, a bit less for other platforms.